# what sql query statement should i use for a vb.net application?

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I have three tables set up in a MySQL database called "event", "status" and "user". (as shown below:

**EVENT TABLE** (below)
[image: Event Table]

**STATUS TABLE** (below)
[image: Status Table]

**USER TABLE** (below)
[image: User Table]

and when I get data from the event table I use the SQL query statement below to bind the persons first and last names together as one variable called "name" and then bind that name to the respective user_id; and so on. However when I make changes to the event table it doesn't show the changes I've made. I'm certain it has something to do with the way I'm retrieving the data.

```
SELECT CONCAT(u.lastname, ', ', u.firstname) AS Name
       , s.message AS Message
       , DATE_FORMAT(e.timestamp,'%b %d %Y - %r') AS DateTime
       , e.status AS Status 
FROM event e 
LEFT JOIN status s ON e.message_id = s.message_id
          , user u 
WHERE(e.user_id = u.user_id)
  AND event_id IN(
      SELECT MAX(e.event_id) FROM event e 
      GROUP BY e.user_id)
ORDER BY name
```

So I am in need of a new SQL query statement that will take the information in those three tables and produce a data grid view in my vb.net program that will look similar to this:

[image: Resulting Table]

But will also accept any changes I make to the database through the data grid view in my vb.net program; Or if my problem has nothing to do with the query statement, then I'd like to know how to fix this.

If you want to see the basic layout of my database (minus the personal information) then here is the script for my database.

```
CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `in_out`;
USE `in_out`;
CREATE TABLE `admin_levels` (
  `level_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `title` char(20) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`level_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
CREATE TABLE `event` (
  `event_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `user_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `message_id` mediumint(8) unsigned default '0',
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `status` enum('In','Out') NOT NULL default 'In',
  `creator` smallint(5) unsigned default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`event_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
INSERT INTO `event` (`event_id`,`user_id`,`message_id`,`timestamp`,`status`,`creator`) VALUES 
 (1,1,1,'2005-01-17 11:50:00','Out',1),
 (2,2,1,'2005-01-17 11:57:00','Out',2),
 (3,3,1,'2005-01-17 11:59:00','Out',3),
 (4,1,3,'2005-01-17 13:30:00','In',1),
 (5,2,3,'2005-01-17 13:30:00','In',2),
 (6,3,3,'2005-01-17 13:30:00','In',3),
 (7,2,2,'2005-01-17 16:00:00','Out',2),
 (8,3,2,'2005-01-17 16:10:00','Out',3),
 (9,1,NULL,'2005-01-17 15:19:49','In',1);
CREATE TABLE `groups` (
  `group_name` char(20) NOT NULL default '',
  `created` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `scope` enum('Public','Private') default NULL,
  `deleted` enum('True','False') default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`group_name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
CREATE TABLE `status` (
  `message_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `user_id` smallint(5) unsigned default NULL,
  `message` char(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `deleted` enum('True','False') default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`message_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
INSERT INTO `status` (`message_id`,`user_id`,`message`,`deleted`) VALUES 
 (1,NULL,'Gone to Lunch','False'),
 (2,NULL,'Gone For The Day','False'),
 (3,NULL,'In Meeting','False');
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `lastname` char(40) NOT NULL default '',
  `firstname` char(40) NOT NULL default '',
  `phone` char(10) NOT NULL default '',
  `username` char(16) NOT NULL default '',
  `password` char(40) character set latin1 collate latin1_bin NOT NULL default '',
  `administrator` enum('TRUE','FALSE') NOT NULL default 'TRUE',
  `deleted` enum('TRUE','FALSE') NOT NULL default 'TRUE',
  `created` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
INSERT INTO `user` (`user_id`,`lastname`,`firstname`,`phone`,`username`,`password`,`administrator`,`deleted`,`created`) VALUES 
 (1,'Hillyer','Mike','4033806535','mike','12345','TRUE','FALSE','2004-11-27 11:41:00'),
 (2,'Jones','Tom','4035551212','bob','54321','FALSE','FALSE','2005-01-17 13:52:00'),
 (3,'Johnson','Julie','4035551213','julie','weakpass','FALSE','FALSE','2005-01-17 13:55:00');
CREATE TABLE `user_group` (
  `group_name` char(20) NOT NULL default '',
  `user_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `level_id` tinyint(3) unsigned default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`user_id`,`group_name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Combining explicit SQL '92 and implicit SQL '89 join syntax, that's a first ! It almost shines in it's ugliness.

Comment: please don't link to an crappy download site like megaupload. As long as SO doesn't complain about the post being too long, it's far better to just post the data.

Comment: Oh and -1, for paste pictures where you could have pasted copy-pastable text, using megaupload and mixing SQL '89 and SQL '92 syntax.

Comment: ok first of all i don't know of a better site than megaupload therefore i had no other choice (to my knowledge). second of all what is "SO"? and finally, no offense but i was hoping for advice/help not criticism...

Comment: how was i suppose to "paste copy-pastable text" from a table?

Comment: and i don't even know what sql '89 and '92 syntax is... so forgive me if im not a perfectionist

Comment: if all your going to do is pick everything i've said apart and not offer any information that is relevant to my request then please stop

Comment: SQL '89 syntax: `select a.*, b.* from a,b where a.id = b.a_id` uses implicit joins. SQL '92 syntax `select a.*, b.* from a inner join b ON a.id = b.a_id` uses explicit joins. This separates the join criteria from the filter criteria and makes your queries much easier to debug.

Comment: oh, that makes things alot easier to understand, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 SELECT CONCAT(u.lastname + ', ' + u.firstname) AS Name
   , s.message AS Message
   , DATE_FORMAT(e.timestamp,'%b %d %Y - %r') AS DateTime
   , e.status AS Status 
FROM event e 
LEFT JOIN status s ON e.message_id = s.message_id inner join user u on e.user_id = u.user_id

WHERE event_id IN(
  SELECT MAX(e.event_id) FROM event e 
  GROUP BY e.user_id)
ORDER BY name
```

Comment: also save this as a store procedure in sqlserver and use as a datasouce in your application and every change you make in sql should show

Comment: im assuming by store procedure you mean routine in mysql workbench, and do you mean just add it to the list of routines or actually save it on my computer and import it in visual basic express. Also, how do i use it as a data source ? it's not showing up on the list...

Answer (score 0):

Please rewrite the query like so.

```
SELECT CONCAT(u.lastname, ', ', u.firstname) AS Name
       , s.message AS Message
       , DATE_FORMAT(e.`timestamp`,'%b %d %Y - %r') AS DateTime
       , e.status AS Status 
FROM event e 
LEFT JOIN status s ON e.message_id = s.message_id
INNER JOIN user u ON (e.user_id = u.user_id)
WHERE e.event_id IN(
      SELECT MAX(e.event_id) FROM event e 
      GROUP BY e.user_id)
ORDER BY name
```

> However when I make changes to the event table it doesn't show the changes I've made. I'm certain it has something to do with the way I'm retrieving the data

**Why don't I see any changes I make to the `event` table?**

I think you want to show the output of the above query in a dataview and also **enter data into** that view.
That last thing is impossible for a view that is not fed by a anything other than a simple query like:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
```

The reason is that SQL has no idea how to place the data the tables used, nor does it want to know.

If you make changes to the `event` table itself, you will see those of course when you rerun the query **and** if they meet the criteria in the `select` statement.

Comment: so if i can't use your revised sql query above and update the data too, then what solution do you propose? and yes i want to see the output of the above query and when i enter data into that view couldn't i just do the whole process in reverse? unbind the name, and split it into first and last names, split the message from its id and so on?

Comment: you said "... for a view that is not fed by anything other than a simple query..." what else can i feed it?

Comment: all i want to do is be able to both display, and change information on my database using a vb.net client program

Comment: @daniel, you cannot do that, if you want to feed it you will have to make a query to feed the database `INSERT INTO event (user_id, message_id, timestamp, status, creator) VALUES (345, 54545, NOW(), 0,0)`. You cannot create a query _(other than `select * from x`)_ and expect it to work both ways. SQL is not clairvoyant.

Comment: @daniel, BTW a simple query = `select * from x` anything else is not simple enough to work both ways.

Comment: Okay so is there a simple query to display a whole table in a data grid view?

Comment: so what would be the easiest way to edit my database from a vb.net application

Comment: @daniel11, I seems to me you are a: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem